# System.BadImageFormatException on running ServiceStack examples.

Tags: sqlite, badimageformatexception, servicestack

I am trying to run [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) Examples projects. When I run the web client I am getting the following error:

```
{System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an 
    incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
    at Mono.Data.Sqlite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_open_v2(Byte[] utf8Filename, 
    IntPtr& db, Int32 flags, IntPtr vfs)
    at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum 
    flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
    at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnection.Open()
    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection()
    at ServiceStack.Examples.ServiceInterface.Support.ConfigureDatabase
         .Init(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
    in E:\ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Examples\
    ServiceStack.Examples.ServiceInterface\Support\ConfigureDatabase.cs:line 23}
```

I have downloaded latest System.Data.SQLite.dll file and tried to use it, but am getting still the same error. I am running 64-bit VS2010 on Windows 7 64-bit box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the platform target of your main project to x86 to fix this. This can be done under *Project... -> Properties -> Build*.

SqlLite is most likely a 32-bit components, and to be able to load it your application needs to be a 32-bit application as well (64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit components and vice versa).

Comment: I've tried **Any CPU**, **x86** but still getting same error.

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem when trying to load the 32bit sqlite.dll with a 64bit IIS/pc.

To get it to work you need to 'Enable 32-bit Applications' for your AppDomain by:

1. Opening up IIS Manager
2. Click 'Advanced Settings' on your Application Pool.
3. Set **Enable 32-bit Applications** to true

For a more timely response feel free to send a link to any ServiceStack related questions to the [ServiceStack Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/servicestack).

Update: I forgot to add: you also need your top-most level project (i.e. your ASP.NET web application) to have its build configuration set to x86 (32bit).

If you download the **[latest version of ServiceStack.Examples (v2.01)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/downloads)** this should now work on 64bit servers.

More information about this can be tracked on:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/servicestack/EUPqF2jI4ig/discussion