# Getting ServiceStack example to work

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack. I am testing out the MovieREST example. When I run the project, the Immediate Window shows me this error

`"A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Mono.Data.Sqlite.DLL"`

and no movie list is loading up. So, there is only a blank "Add a new movie" page with some default inputs, everytime I hit Add new movie, the DllNotFoundException will be thrown.

Do I need to install any dependency projects to make it work? I am running it with VS2010, IIS, and Vista 32bit (yup..I know..). Also installed Mono and sqlite 32bit just now blindly, I am not even sure if the project needs them to run. From the code, I can see it is referring to "App_Data/db.sqlite" and References already has sqlite3.dll, I replaced the dll with the 32bit one I download anyway, but still no luck.

Please give me some hints on what I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Mono.Data.Sqlite.DLL` is just a managed wrapper that needs to find the unmanaged `sqlite3.dll` in order to run (which is what holds the native binary of Sqlite itself).

It looks for this in the `/bin` directory, to have it deployed there whenever you build you need to copy `sqlite3.dll` to your project root `/` and set the **Build Action** to **Content** and change the Copy action to `Copy if newer`.

Ideally you'd want to use the right `sqlite3.dll` for your architecture (the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono) NuGet package contains both 32bit / 64bit dlls) although IIS/.NET can work with 32bit unmanaged dlls but will [require some tweaking explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657087/system-badimageformatexception-on-running-serivcestack-examples).

### Using mixed-mode assemblies

Whilst `Mono.Data.Sqlite.DLL` lets you run the same .NET app on Mono, if you only want to run Sqlite in Windows you can also use the mixed-mode assemblies that have the unmanaged native sqlite library embedded in the .NET dll. There are 2 different versions available on NuGet:

- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32)
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64)

Remove any references to existing OrmLite or Sqlite dlls as both of these NuGet packages contain all the Sqlite + OrmLite dlls needed.

Comment: Hi mythz thanks for looking at my question! :D I have the sqlite3.dll (492kb) generated by the project itself when I compile it. Also tried the NuGet package sqlite3.dll (x86 585kb). I put them in the /bin/ folder 1 by 1. Both seem to throw me the same DllNotFoundException, but the sqlite3.dll 32bit version is right there sitting next to Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll in the same folder. I looked at the tweaking explained post, it seemed to be a 64bit pc problem where it needed to enable 32bit apps.

Comment: Update: Also tried shortcut and actual sqlite3.dll (as content copy if newer) at project root / too. Same DllNotFoundException.

Comment: It should just work like that, I've added some notes on how you can use the mixed-mode assemblies instead. They have less moving parts so you should be more successful.

Comment: As you said, I removed the lib/ folder for the examples folder and update the project missing references with nuget, deleted the root / sqlite3.dll ref link. Then everything works :D I get to see the demo working. Will deal with mono later, one step at a time! Thank you very much for your help mythz!