# ServiceStack OrmLite Sqlite exception

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, badimageformatexception

I have the following lines of code:

```cs
IDbConnection dbConn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection();
IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
```

I am getting the following exception:

> BadImageFormatException
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

I thought this might have to do with 32 bit and 64 bit applications, so I tried both versions of the dll. In addition, I also enabled 32 bit applications through IIS. Can someone tell me why I may be getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this is a result of trying to use a 32bit unamanged dll (Sqlite) on a 64bit pc.

See [this answer for solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657087/system-badimageformatexception-on-running-serivcestack-examples).

Otherwise use a platform-specific Sqlite .NET wrapper:

- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32/)
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64/)

Comment: I created a new project, cause all my references were messy. Added reference to servicestack, and then added the 64 bit wrapper reference. In addition, I also modified the project build properties like you suggested. However, I am still seeing the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it. There was no need for x86 on build when I had the 64 bit wrapper. Dunno why I did that. Thanks for your help !