# SQLite error when saving data in Window 8 Surface RT App after Deployment

Tags: sqlite, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am a bit new to Windows 8 Store Apps development.

We have development an application with MVVM architecture which uses SQLite 1.07 version to store data offline. Everything works fine in Windows 8 Simulator.

Now when we deploy app in Windows 8 Surface RT and try to save data in SQLite we are getting error saying

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT 0x8007000B)

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: [Is package created for ARM processor](http://i.imgur.com/n1rSu48.png) ? When you add SQLite, you need to specify project platform, AnyCPU doesn't work.

Comment: @Xyroid Yes its created for ARM, I also tried with Release and Debug mode too.

Comment: Try these : [System.BadImageFormatException on running SerivceStack examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657087/system-badimageformatexception-on-running-serivcestack-examples) and [“An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format” even when the platforms are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p)

Comment: Have you added SQLite DLL in your project explicitly or using [visual studio gallery Package](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e) ?